# Unable to set default values in a formGroup with Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-formbuilder

I have tried to pass values in a `FormGroup` object this way :

```
private _doSettingsForm() {

    const settings: SettingsInterface = this.account.settings;
    console.info('Form from settingsForm : \n' + JSON.stringify(settings));

    this.changeSettings = this.formBuilder.group({
        useVocalMode: [
            settings.useVocalMode
        ],
        notificationTime: [
            settings.notificationTime.format('HH:mm')
        ],
        maxPurchaseRadius: [
            settings.maxPurchaseRadius,
            [
                Validators.min(this.purchaseBounds.lower),
                Validators.max(this.purchaseBounds.higher)
            ]
        ]
    });

    console.info('changeSettings : ' + typeof this.changeSettings);
}
```

But, the `FormGroup` isn't created. If ever I pass some hard values instead of values from my interface, it's ok.

I don't know what I'm missing.

Note : settings are correctly populate

Note : imports are

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well... The problem was on the `notificationTime` property. I had considered it as a `moment` object, but was a `JSON` time.
So, I just changed it from:

```
notificationTime: [
    settings.notificationTime.format('HH:mm')
],
```

to :

```
notificationTime: [
    settings.notificationTime
],
```

and form is okay... Just have to get the correct hour that is hour - 2 (6 instead of 4).